# PyOpenGL: no module named GL

Tags: python, pyopengl

I have just installed the latest version of PyOpenGL through easy_install on Ubuntu 14.04 and even after following tutorials correctly on installing this library, I keep getting the error:

```
No Module Named GL
```

which means I cant do any basic OpenGL stuff. Please help:(
here is what I've got so far:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You must install OpenGL via `pip install PyOpenGL` on the cmd and it will apply to any code editor or compiler you have on your pc. The accessibility of python is very high up in comparison to others, which is why me and many others use it. As mentioned above, installing via `pip install` binds to the path and is automatically assigned as global on the main sys.